# How to set value in .net tag helper attribute using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am trying to set parameter value read from a textbox on the page to this link:

```
<a asp-action="RetrieveEmailRecipients" asp-route-clientnumber="getClientNumber()">Retrieve Email Recipients</a>
```

And I have Javascript down somewhere else at the bottom of the page. But appreatly this is not the right way to pass value to MVC action method's parameter.

What parameter ClientNumber read in action is whatever the string/value in asp-route-clientnumber, in this case the value is getClientNumber().

What is the correct way to set value in the attribute using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are mixing server side code and client side code together

I am assuming your `getClientNumber()` is a javascript function

Tag Helper is generated **before** javascript comes in, so when server is generating the html, it has no knowledge of what `getClientNumber()`
is so will treated as literal string

So the proper way of doing it will be modify the url with jquery when client number available

Something like:

1. give the anchor an identifier - so you can access it using jquery easily and remove the route

   ```
   <a id="aRetriveEmail" asp-action="RetrieveEmailRecipients">Retrieve Email Recipients</a>
   ```
2. modify the attribute of the anchor to include your clientNumber whenever you have clientNumber ready, or use javascript to navigate to it

   ```
   $(function(){
       $("#aRetriveEmail").click(function(){
           // example of how modifying href when client number ready
           // $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?clientnumber=" + getClientNumber());

           // or navigate to the url
           location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "?clientnumber=" + getClientNumber();
       })
   })
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking about that, but saw some post on stackoverflow showing that invoking javascript in the attribute works, that's why I thought it might be something else wrong.

Comment: I think the solution I want also needs to remove the asp-action attribute in the a tag. Otherwise it will also make another call to the same action method without passing any value. I noticed that from browser's developer tool.

Comment: do you still have the link to the stackoverflow post which said invoking javascript in the attribute work?
you will need `asp-action` so it will generate the url using default controller and specific action (in your case `RetrieveEmailRecipients`)
what is your `getClientNumber()` doing? if you don't need info from the client, you may try convert same logic into c# then you could call it while generating the anchor

Comment: getClientNumber() is just a javascript function which returns the value for client number field on the page, like this: $('#ClientNumber').val(). The reason I said it doesn't seem needing the asp-action attribute is, in the browser's developer tool, I noticed 2 calls to the RetrieveEmailRecipients method in controller. 1st one with parameters I want, 2nd one doesn't. But in the end, I used ajax call as I am GET data from the backend, doesn't really need to redirect, so a new url would not be necessary in here. Thank you for your help.